# Mocha JS - mock parent class module

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, mocha.js

## Background

I have class `A` that extends from class `B`:

```
A = class A
    ...
    my_inner_func: (param1) =>
        return new MyHelper()

B = class B extends A
    ...
```

## What I want to do?

In the unittest, `my_inner_func()` should return `MyMockHelper()`.

## What I've tried

```
a = rewire './a.coffee'
b = rewire './b.coffee'

a.__set__
    MyHelper: MyMockHelper

b.__set__
    A: a.A
```

But `B().my_inner_func()` returns `MyHelper` instead of `MyMockHelper`.

## My question

How does one mock a module used by an extended class in CoffeeScript (or JavaScript)?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for rewire doesn't say anything about class instance variables.  I think its really just for "rewiring" the globals or top-level scope of the module under test.

Also, rewire has a few [limitations](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire#limitations).  Among them, support for const or babel seems to be ify, so perhaps try a native solution?

At a basic level, a mock is simply overriding or replacing a method on an object's prototype, so something like this should work in your test case

```
// super class
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
// superclass instance
const rect = new Polygon(10, 2);
console.log('rect', rect.area); // 20

// subclass
class Square extends Polygon {
  constructor(side) {
    super(side, side)
  }
}

// subclass instance
const square = new Square(2);
console.log('square', square.area); // 4

// mocked calcArea of subclass
square.calcArea = function() {
    return 0;
};

// result from new mocked calcArea
console.log('mocked', square.area); // 0
```

using mocha might look like this...

```
import Square from './Square';

describe('mocks', () => {

    it('should mock calcArea', () => {

        const square = new Square(2);

        square.calcArea = function() {
            return 0;
        };

        expect(square.area).to.equal(0);
    });

});
```

Here's a [code pen](http://codepen.io/adjavaherian/pen/LRYkGQ/?editors=0011) to play around with